# How to resize an image inside an UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have this UIButton and an image to fit in. 
I don't want that the image take all the space inside the button but just a little part of it right in the center, but if I resize the button it will resize the image too.
How can I do that, is there an option to set whatever dimension I want independently from the size of the UIButton?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to do this through Interface Builder or through code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done through code in the following way:

```
    let imageSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)

    let button:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 60, height: 60)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "chat.png"), for: UIControl.State.normal)

    // The below line will give you what you want
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
        top: (button.frame.size.height - imageSize.height) / 2,
        left: (button.frame.size.width - imageSize.width) / 2,
        bottom: (button.frame.size.height - imageSize.height) / 2,
        right: (button.frame.size.width - imageSize.width) / 2)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

This way, you can achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 14):

I couldn't get the button's imageView to resize until I used contentHorizontalAlignment and contentVerticalAlignment both set to .fill. Then using imageEdgeInsets I repositioned the image.

```
let button = UIButton()
let image = UIImage(systemName: "bag.badge.plus")
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can experiment with image view insets. Every UIButton has a property imageView.

In Swift 3 you can do this like so:

```
//let button = UIButton()
button.imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

red background is just so you know what is changing

Answer (score 8):

I would do it this way:

A `UIButton` is just a `UIView`. You can simply add a `UIImageView` with a set image and call `addSubview` on the `UIButton`.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, but this was helpful to me!

Comment: userInteractionEnabled is set to false on default for UIImageView

Comment: I can't believe i never new about this, now i don't have to struggle with insets haha! thanks

Comment: An example would have been very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Taking into account what KVISH said before i have implemented this and it worked as expected. I posted this because Houman asked for an example.

```
//grab the image using the name of the pic
var image = UIImage(named: "picture")

//set the size for the image
image = image?.resize(toWidth: 18)
image = image?.resize(toHeight: 18)

//set the image to the button
buttonName.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)

//adjust the position
buttonName.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8,16,9,0)
```

Comment: This should be the correct one, for me just changing imageEdgeInsets is not making the image smaller or bigger.

Comment: Agreed, `imageEdgeInsets` also works for shrinking image, but only in the case of button size is determined. This approach is more flexible and better.

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 13, when using SF Symbols, I prefer this:

```
let button = UIButton()
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30) // <- make it larger, smaller, whatever you want. 
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(font: font)
let image = UIImage(systemName: "bag.badge.plus", withConfiguration: config)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

These can be achieved by adding imageEdgeInsets to a UIButton.

In swift4.2

```
  button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Comment: how this answer is different than above answers?